# jest.spyOn method that return a Promise

Tags: node.js, jestjs, es6-promise

I'm trying to test an application but [jest.spyOn](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) is make me crazy.

I'm working on node v8.9.4 and jest v22.2.2

I have extracted this code:

```
// my-module.js
class MySingletonModule {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }
  myPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(this.foo));
  }
}

module.exports = new MySingletonModule();
```

---

```
// promise.test.js
const singleton = require('./my-module');
describe('Module test-suite', () => {
  let spy;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    spy = jest.fn();
    spy = jest.spyOn(singleton, 'myPromise');
  });

  beforeEach(() => spy.mockReset());

  test('Check bar', () => {
    return singleton.myPromise().then((bar) => {
      expect(bar).toEqual('bar');
    });
  });

  test('Check called times', () => {
    singleton.myPromise();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
});
```

The `Check bar` test is failing because the `myPromise` method doesn't return a promise:

[image: the error]

If I comment the `spy = jest.spyOn(singleton, 'myPromise');` the test works.. but obviously the other test doesn't works..

[image]

I would expect that all the tests work with `spyOn`, because reading the docs is wrote:

> Note: By default, jest.spyOn also calls the spied method.

I'm missing something?

Thanks for the help

Comment: just as a comment, you know you can use async functions if you're using node 8, like test('Check bar', async () => {
    const bar = await singleton.myPromise()
    expect(bar).toEqual('bar');
  });

Comment: mh, thats a weird one, maybe the `spy = jest.fn();` line above leads to that? Try removing it

Comment: I have wrote that only for switch between line 7 and 8 easily. I tried that but nothing has changed

Comment: My guess is this is a failure to call through to the function. I would expect you get the exact same problem if you return *anything*, not just a Promise. Is that true? (For example, try returning the object `{ then: f=>f(this.foo) }`) It might be related to `mockReset`, possibly?

Comment: No, even with a simple `return 42;` the function, after is spied, return `undefined`

Comment: Spying on a method you call directly defeats the purpose of spying altogether...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working snippet without Jasmine:

```
describe('Module test-suite', () => {
  let spy;

  beforeAll(() => { // get rid of async
    spy = jest.fn();
    spy = jest.spyOn(singleton, 'myPromise');
  });

  afterEach(() => spy.mockRestore()); // main difference is here

  test('Check bar', () => {
    return singleton.myPromise().then((bar) => {
      expect(bar).toEqual('bar');
    });
  });

  test('Check called times', () => {
    singleton.myPromise();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
});
```

I think it's better to use `mockRestore` instead of `mockReset`, because as I understand from [jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockreset) `mockReset` hardly clears all information about spy and spying object. And `mockRestore` just clears some temp data such as number of called times.

Why is using `afterEach` instead of `beforeEach` important - I have no clue :(

Also I removed `async` because tests failed with it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any mention of this in the documentation but it seems like jest allows you to use a lot of Jasmine's functionality / syntax, including `.and.callThrough`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  spyOn(singleton, 'myPromise').and.callThrough();
};

test('Check bar', async () => {
  const bar = await singleton.myPromise();
  expect(bar).toEqual('bar');
});

test('Check called times', () => {
  singleton.myPromise();
  expect(singleton.myPromise.calls.count()).toBe(1);
});
```

Here are the jasmine spy docs: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

If you want to stick to the documented `jest.spyOn` API then you can instead set the spy inside of the test that uses it, so that it doesn't affect the other:

```
test('Check bar', async () => {
  const bar = await singleton.myPromise();
  expect(bar).toEqual('bar');
});

test('Check called times', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(singleton, 'myPromise');
  singleton.myPromise();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: The second code block works. Do you think that the correct use is this? It is wrong count the called times based in the other tests?

Comment: I think it’s fine to count the spy’s calls for all tests as long as the spy is being reset each time

Comment: But how you would that without jasmine (and only with jest) if, after build a spy, all the successive call return undefined?

Comment: `.and.callThrough();` This is what saved my day. Thanks mate.